# How to insert text into placeholder in a string?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to put the `Environment.UserName` inside of the Path for my `Process.Start` call, below is the code I currently have:

```
private void viewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\Users\{0}\Documents\Content\New folder", Environment.UserName);
}
```

How do I put replace the `{0}` with the Environment.UserName?

Comment: I don't think a folder name is actually the name of an executable command... in Windows you can open folders using explorer.exe ...

Comment: What you are even trying to achieve here? Title says you are trying to get `Environment.UserName` but from given code it looks like you are trying to start new process

Comment: You don't have to find the username, nor write code that fails to work on non-English language systems - just ask the system for the correct [Special Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-5.0)

Comment: the {0} part is where I'm trying to get the current environment username

Comment: Before the `@` put a `$` and change the `0` to be the `Environment.UserName` this will insert the Username inside of the `{}` like so: `$@"C:\Users\{Environment.UserName}\Documents\Content\New folder"`

Comment: thats got it working thank you!

Comment: @bigj20202 I'll put it as the answer if you could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After discussion in the comments, the issue was that he was wanting to place the `Environment.UserName` inside of the `{0}` in the Path.

So, with that being said, using Interpolated Verbatim strings ([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation#:~:text=An%20interpolated%20verbatim%20string%20starts,%22%20or%20%22%7D%7D%22.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation#:%7E:text=An%20interpolated%20verbatim%20string%20starts,%22%20or%20%22%7D%7D%22.)) is what he was requesting, like so:

`$@"C:\Users\{Environment.UserName}\Documents\Content\New folder"`

Comment: Which is exactly the wrong way to solve the problem since it assumes the structure of the file system layout, when there are specific tools built to allow you to get to the most appropriate folder

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the problem the user was having, wasn't related to the structure of the file system. It may be a personal project that will only be executed on specific users machines where the structure of the file system / layout is exactly the same, e.g an internal application in an office environment where all computers C drives are structured the same with least privileges for the users, prevent them from being changed.

The question he had was to put the `Environment.Username` in the Path, that is what the code above does.

Comment: If someone asks the best way of fixing antique furniture using a sledge hammer and railway spikes, do you answer the question or suggest they may have picked the wrong tools?

Comment: That is irrelevant, if someone has a simple question with a possible simple solution, would you over complicate it and make it harder for them to understand what the solution you provided was? No, you'd keep it simple, the user who asked the question in this case is a New Contributor and from the code they gave in their example, they seem new, so keeping it simple, giving a reference to learning material is a better solution than overcomplicating and creating a `problem` which may not even exist.

Comment: Exactly right, this is for an internal application in an office, the answer given has solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your original question is how to substitute a placeholder in a string.
For this ConnorTJ 's answer is perfectly fine. Interpolated strings are the preferred way to go.

```
string s = $"The current users name is {Environment.UserName}.";
```

Alternatively you could use `string.Format`:

```
string s = string.Format("The current users name is {0}.", Environment.UserName);
```

But as also others have already mentioned there are better ways to retrieve system folders. For getting the document folder you'd better use

```
string docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

For adding the subfolder use `System.IO.Path.Combine()`:

```
string folder = Path.Combine(docFolder, @"Content\New folder");
```

Starting a process and just passing a folder works because it will open the application which is assigned to folders, most likely Windows Explorer. Anyhow, if you want to make sure that Windows Explorer will be opened i'd reccomend to explicitely start Explorer and pass the folder as argument:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", folder);
```